# pyinstaller flask app fatal error running .exe

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller

I am looking at [this blog post](https://elc.github.io/posts/executable-flask-pyinstaller/) for creating an executable file to run a flask app on Windows. Question, would this be useful if there was a standalone app created for people using that app that were not very computer technical? IE, just run the `.exe` file to open up the app on a localhost web browser versus opening up the command prompt to run a typical flask server...

Im just experimenting with this and I `pip install pyinstaller` as the blog post mentioned, and ran this command `pyinstaller -w -F hello.py` across my test flask code directory.

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Pyinstaller seems to execute everything correctly at least it doesn't look like there are any errors compiling. As the blog post mentions there is a dist folder created and an application(`hello.exe`) file created; but when I click on it to run, a box will pop up `critical error failed to run hello`

Any tips greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting Flask app's `debug=True` which means that you want to run it in debug mode.
On the other hand, you are disabling the python' console in your output executable with `-w` flag. This is your error. Either remove `-w` flag from your Pyinstaller build command or set `debug=False` in your Flask's app.

I suggest you keep the console window because if you get any error in your Flask app you would see the error log in the console.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much that worked. One more question, if I copied the pyinstaller output (`hello.exe`) to another computer would I need to have Python installed on that PC as well as flask & other necessary packages to make my app work? Thanks again

Comment: No, you don't need to. This is the purpose of using Pyinstaller.

Comment: I am attempting this on an actual simple Flask app project, where my project directory contains 2 HTML pages in a `templates` folder and I also have a `static` folder for images. If I run the script to create the .exe file `pyinstaller -F --add-data "templates;templates" --add-data "static;static" app.py` everything executes properly and I can actually run the app.exe as well. (gets me past the initial script error) but I can see there is an error like the `templates` cannot be found. Am I doing anything wrong? Can I send you a link for a different stackoverflow post on this?

Comment: With the app.exe file, I can start the Flask server, but I get an error when attempting to bring up the web page. `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: form.html`.. form.html would be in my templates folder. But it works just fine without using the app.exe and starting typical Flask server thru command prompt

Comment: Sry for the late answer, Your build command is true, but you need to load your files from pyinstaller's temp directory. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204425/how-to-include-images-in-one-file-with-python-pyinstaller/56230557#56230557) would help you. just load your HTML files with `resource_path` function. If you have already asked a question, put the link here, I would answer it.

Comment: Im actually experimenting with `dash` which seems cool to me, there doesnt seem to be a need for a template or static folder directory. I bet there is a lot of dependencies to run dash, but would you know if pyinstaller can work with this?

Comment: I haven't tried using `dash`. But you should be good with Flask and Pyinstaller. There is also a good example in [here](https://github.com/ciscomonkey/flask-pyinstaller)

Comment: @HenryHub place your app.exe file in the directory in which you have your templates folder. This has helped me before.